# overwrite attribute as function Django

Tags: python, django, object, django-models, attributes

I have `class A(models.Model)` with attr `name`. I use it in template and view as `obj_a.name`. I need overwrite `name` attr as function and when I write `obj_a.name` I would get response from function `getName`. How can I do it in `Django` and `Python` ? 
In `Laravel PHP` it is `$this->getNameAttribute()` and I can overwrite returning `name` from object. `Name` is only example and I want use it with almost all attr given class.

```
class Item(caching.base.CachingMixin, models.Model):
    _name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=100, db_column="name",
                         help_text=_('Item name'))

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value
```

Comment: Add your model please

Comment: Added piece of class.

Comment: Did you create and apply migrations after changing `name` to `_name`?

Comment: I can't do it because I got `Unknown field(s) (name) specified for Item`

Comment: Add trace with error

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this behavior with [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

```
class A(models.Model):
    _name = Field()

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
```

Comment: when I did it, I got `Unknown field(s) (name) specified for A`

Answer (score 0):

I found solution ideal for my usage:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    if name == 'name':
        return 'xxx'

    return super(Item, self).__getattribute__(name)
```